# Right and tfeL truncatable primes

Tags: code-golf, primes, source-layout

A [right-truncatable prime](https://oeis.org/A024770) is a prime where every prefix is a prime (in base 10).  A [left-truncatable prime](https://oeis.org/A024785) is exactly the opposite, where every postfix is a prime (primes that start with 0 aren't allowed).  Both of these sequences are finite (There are only 83 Right-truncatables, while there are 4260 Left-truncatables).

You need to write a program that accepts a single number as input, and produces the *n*th right-truncatable prime.  However, when the program is read **arranged backwards**, it should produce the *n*th left-truncatable prime.

To arrange a program backwards, we split the program into words, then reverse the order of the words.  A word can consist of any number of characters.

For example, if the following was your program:

```
hello world
1234567890
```

The following would all be allowed as possible backwards arrangements:

Splitting on each character:

```
0987654321
dlrow olleh
```

Splitting on whitespace:

```
1234567890
world hello
```

Splitting arbitrarily (pipes added for clarity):

```
hel|lo w|orld
1|23456|7|8|90

908723456orld
1lo whel
```

When arranging your program backwards, all whitespace must be considered and reversed, just like any other character.

### Forward test inputs:

```
1:  2
2:  3
21: 379
60: 239933
83: 73939133
```

### Backward test inputs:

```
1:    2
2:    3
39:   647
187:  29173
4260: 357686312646216567629137
```

Programs should be able to run in a reasonable amount of time (less than a minute)

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the program with the fewest bytes wins!

Comment: no.  The atom after `lo w` is `orld\n1`.  The newline doesn't end the atom

Comment: Ah, thanks. Got it now. Removing my two previous comments to avoid confusion

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>26</s> 23 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

### Forward

```
Ñ¶p9¶7ÆR2ĿV€$ÆPÐf$ÐĿFị@
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w5HCtnA5wrY3w4ZSMsS_VuKCrCTDhlDDkGYkw5DEv0bhu4tA&input=&args=ODM)

#### Words

`Ñ` `¶` `p` `9` `¶` `7ÆR2ĿV€$ÆPÐf$ÐĿFị@`

### Backward

```
7ÆR2ĿV€$ÆPÐf$ÐĿFị@¶9p¶Ñ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=N8OGUjLEv1bigqwkw4ZQw5BmJMOQxL9G4buLQMK2OXDCtsOR&input=&args=NDI2MA)

#### Words

`7ÆR2ĿV€$ÆPÐf$ÐĿFị@` `¶` `9` `p` `¶` `Ñ`

### How it works

All Jelly programs consist of links (Jelly's take on functions), which are separated by linefeeds or pilcrows (`¶`). The last of them is the *main link*; it is called automatically when the program is run.

The forward program works as follows.

```
Ñ                   Helper link. Unused.


p9                  Helper link. Take the Cartesian product with [1, ..., 9].


7ÆR2ĿV€$ÆPÐf$ÐĿFị@  Main link. Argument: n

7ÆR                 Yield all primes up to 7.
             ÐĿ     
            $ÐĿ     Combine the two quicklinks to the left into a monadic chain,
                    and call it repeatedly until the results are no longer unique.
                    Return the array of all intermediate results.
       $              Combine the two links to the left into a monadic chain.
   2Ŀ               Call the helper link on line 2.
     Ṿ€                 Eval each array in the product. This casts to string
                        before evaluating, thus concatenating both numbers.
        ÆPÐf        Filter by primality; keep only primes.
               F    Flatten the resulting array.
                ị@  Retrieve the element at index n.
```

The backward program does almost exactly the same; there are only two differences.

- The main link is now `Ñ`, which simply calls the link below it (wrapping around), i.e., the main link of the forward program.
- `9p` instead of `p9` return the reversed Cartesian product.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, <del>143</del> 139 bytes

```
I=1
a={2}
def f(s):
 for d in'123456789':u=d[I:]+s+d*I;z=int(u);z+=z<3;z%91>0<2==pow(2,z,z)>a.add(z)<f(u)
f('')
lambda n:sorted(a)[~-n]
I=0
```

Consists of five parts:

1. `I=1`
2. A newline
3. `a={2}…[~-n]`
4. A newline
5. `I=0`

So reversal is just flipping the value of `I`.

### Explanation

The function `f` performs a recursive search for either left-truncatable primes (LTPs) or right-truncatable primes (RTPs), depending on the value of the global `I`. These values get added to the set `a`. Then, `lambda n:sorted(a)[~-n]` returns the `n`-th one.

Let’s define a **leaf** as either an LTP, an RTP, some non-zero digit + an LTP, or an RTP + some non-zero digit. These are all the values that `f` could ever want to check for primality.

I designed a Fermat pseudoprime test that works for all leaves:

> [image]

(63973 is a [Carmichael number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number).)

If this test returns true, then `z` should be added to the set `a` and we should recurse on `str(z)`. The responsible bit of code is:

> ```
> z+=z<3;z%91>0<2==pow(2,z,z)>a.add(z)<f(u)
> ```

First, we wish to deal with the case `z == 2`. We do so by simply dodging it here and hard-coding `2` when we initially define `a`! (EDIT: And nothing harmful happens if we also catch `z == 1`.) So we can assume that `z ≥ 3` now.

I’ve translated some “and”s into a short-circuiting chained comparison: the first three comparisons have to succeed before `a.add(z)` and `f(u)` are ever evaluated. Here are all their roles:

> 1. `z%91>0` encodes our first condition. (63973 is divisible by 91, which is not a leaf itself, so that’s how we recognize it.)
> 2. `0<2` is always true, but chaining is shorter than `and`.
> 3. `2==pow(2,z,z)` encodes our second condition.
> 4. `pow(2,z,z)>a.add(z)` triggers the addition, and is always true, since `set.add` returns `None`, and integers are always greater than `None`.
> 5. `a.add(z)<f(u)` triggers the recursion. Its truth value is unimportant.

### Acknowledgements

- Dennis saved four bytes (`u=[d+s,s+d][I]` → `u=d[I:]+s+d*I`; `z==2` → `z<3` and the **mod 91** trick). Thanks!